# Getting error while trying to list users in active directory using azure python sdk

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using the below piece of of code :

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient 
credential = AzureCliCredential()
tenant_id = ""
graph_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credential,tenant_id)
users = graph_client.users.list()
for i in users:
    print (i.user_principal_name)
```

When I am using the above code its giving me the below error :

```
AttributeError: 'AzureCliCredential' object has no attribute 'signed_session'
```

If I remove the iteration for paged context of the users . then there is no error and i get output as :

```
<azure.graphrbac.models.user_paged.UserPaged object at 0x0000025125C1B250>
```

Please help in getting the list of the users from the paged context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using the same code but authenticating with service principal . I got an error, that insufficient privileges as the `GraphrbacManagementClient` uses the `Azure AD graph legacy API` permissions to get the users which is deprecated and I couldn't add the permissions for the service principal.

As a Solution I used `msgraph-core` module to get the issue fixed which use `Microsoft Graph API`.

**You can install the package using the below command:**

```
pip install msgraph-core
```

**After installation you can use the below code :**

```
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential
from msgraph.core import GraphClient 
clientid= "clientID or AppID"
clientsecret = "secret for the service principal"
tenantid = "tenantid"
credentials=ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id=tenantid,client_id=clientid,client_secret=clientsecret) 
graph_client = GraphClient(credential=credentials)
users = graph_client.get('/users?$select=userPrincipalName,id')
print(users.json())
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Any idea on if I want to add users to the group?