# trying to list users and check their status in azure ad with microsoft graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am following the getting started code example from MS using an Azure app to pragmatically hit the graph api with Python. This is copied from MS getting started guide, and this is my app permissions, but i still keep getting insufficient privileges error, what more permissions do i need?

```
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient

credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
    client_id="my_id",
    secret="my_secret",
    resource="https://graph.windows.net",
    tenant = 'my_tenant'
)
tenant_id = 'my_tenant_id'
graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(credentials,tenant_id)


users = graphrbac_client.users.list()
print(users)
for user in users:           # permissions error here
     print(user.user_principal_name)

groups = graphrbac_client.groups.list()
print(groups)
for g in groups:           # permissions error here
     print(g.display_name)
```

My errors for the two sections of code:

```
azure_ad_testing.py", line 16, in <module>
    for user in users:
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
line 21, in <module>
    for g in groups:
azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

My app permissions[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is stuck i found the solution here: [Azure Python SDK - Interact with Azure AD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58260616/azure-python-sdk-interact-with-azure-ad)

But regardless, you should be switching to microsoft graph and not user AzureAD sdk since they are depreciating them

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are using the GraphRbacManagementClient . This is deprecated and uses the (also deprecated) Azure AD graph legacy API permissions to get the users. Instead you can use the msgraph-core module, which uses Microsoft Graph API. There is a similar question with a sample code here: [Getting error while trying to list users in active directory using azure python sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69733165/getting-error-while-trying-to-list-users-in-active-directory-using-azure-python)

Otherwise that error typically means that the admin consent hasn't been granted, but I see from your screenshot that it has.

Note also that to list the members of a group with hidden membership, the Member.Read.Hidden permission is required.

Additional related topic, for further reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197819/insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation?page=2#answers

Comment: I believe the root cause for us was that the "API/Permission name" (first column) was set for Microsoft Graph and not Azure AD Graph. But yeah when we saw the deprecation notice we went to just use MSAL library and requests since our use case is rather simple. TY though!